# How to access endpoints in a controller in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a controller class this way with endpoints. I know that we can access RESTful endpoints in a web application through a tool like 'postman' using the URL. But I am not sure how to access these endpoints. This is not a web application.

This is a java application deployed as a JAR on server using embedded tomcat.

How can I access these endpoints?

```
@Controller
public class TopicStatsController {

    @Autowired
    private QueueDepths depths;

    @RequestMapping("/topicDepth")
    @ResponseBody
    public Long topicDepth() throws Exception {
        return depths.topicDepth();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/subscribersDepth")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Long> subscribersDepth() throws Exception {
        return depths.subscribersDepth();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is is still a web application, either deployed as a war on a traditional Tomcat server or executed as a jar with an embedded Tomcat. Just issue a GET with Postman or curl to i.e. `localhost:<port>/topicDepth`

Comment: If you are using `spring-boot` with `web-starter` in your `pom.xml`, it is a web application even if this is a standalone JAR and not deployed on a web server. That's the beauty of spring-boot.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Where should I issue a GET with Postman ?The application is on a remote server not on my computer. How can I say localhost:<port>/topicDepth for an application on a remote server?

Comment: @hars replace `localhost:<port>` with your remote server's `IP:<port>`

Comment: You have not accepted an answer to any of your questions. Consider accepting an answer if it has solved your problem. Check out [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 1):

You can access the endpoints using [RestTemplate](http://www.baeldung.com/rest-template).

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String fooResourceUrl
  = "/topicDepth";
ResponseEntity<String> response
  = restTemplate.getForEntity(fooResourceUrl + "/1", Long.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your remote must be having an **IP address** and a **port number**.

You can use it to hit a `GET` or `POST` request.

On localhost - `http://localhost:8080/myapp-oracle/api/v1/user`

On remote - `http://172.16.254.1:8080/myapp-oracle/api/v1/user`

**Note:** You also need to change the http protocol depending upon the server.